# video source can't be started DOM exception

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-capture

**Error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source
```

**What I tried:**
I checked that is my chrome is allowed to access camera and it was allowed.
I tried to updated my camera drive but no updates were available.
This error comes mostly but sometimes my site doesn't give this error.
How to resolve this issue?
It is a problem of my laptop and it is still saying that my code has an error pls give any solutions 
**Code:**

```
getDevices: async function(){
    let $this = this;
    navigator.mediaDevices
    .enumerateDevices()
    .then(function(devices) {
        devices.forEach(function(device) {
            if(device.kind == "audioinput"){
                $this.microphones.push(device);
            }
            else if(device.kind == "audiooutput"){
                $this.speakers.push(device);
            }
            else if(device.kind == "videoinput"){
                $this.cameras.push(device);
            }
        });
     });
    let videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true,audio: false});
    let audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false,audio: true});
    const combinedStream = new MediaStream(
        [
            ...videoStream.getVideoTracks(),
            ...audioStream.getAudioTracks()
        ]
    );

    document.getElementById("myVideo").srcObject=combinedStream;
    document.getElementById("myVideo").muted = true;
},
setCamera: async function(){
    let videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{deviceId:this.selectedCamera},audio: false});
    let audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false,audio: true});
    const combinedStream = new MediaStream(
        [
            ...videoStream.getVideoTracks(),
            ...audioStream.getAudioTracks()
        ]
    );

    document.getElementById("myVideo").srcObject=combinedStream;
    document.getElementById("myVideo").muted = true;
}, //It says that The error is on this line and the error is Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source.
```

-Thanks For All Your Solutions

Comment: **(1)** Double-check... _"//It says that The error is on this line"_ all you have on that line is `},` which is not enough to trigger a video source error. The error should be where you change video source and/or attempt to use the video tag in some way (but source is not ready)... Why do your functions end with `,` like at each `async function(){ ..code.. },`?

Comment: Actually, I got to know that it is my laptop's problem not the code because even in google meet it is saying same error .